# Android RelativeLayout - TextView overlap button... why?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have the below `xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/addTimerButton"    
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:onClick="addTimer"  
     />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/addTimerButton"
        android:text="00:00:00" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv2"
        android:text="00:00:00" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

The first `TextView tv1` is correctly under the button but `tv2` actually overlap the button. I'd expect `tv2` to be below `tv1`...

Can someone help clarify how this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have made a typo.

The `android:layout_below` property of your second `TextView` is incorrect. So this property is skipped and this `TextView` is placed at his default position which is at the top left. That is why it overlaps your button.

To fix it just replace this :

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv2"
        android:text="00:00:00" />
```

by this :

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv1"
        android:text="00:00:00" />
```